# Handing multiple scenes in andengine is cause "Consumer closed input channel" exception

Tags: android, andengine

I am doing a simple POC of andengine Scene handling. I have written a simple code, that adds and remove a scene to parent scene as a child.

After doing several time this action, game crashes with following logs.

ANy information or details about these logs and its reasons would be of great help.

```
04-18 23:43:12.410: D/AndEngine(9346): SpeedyMindActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=800,  Height=480) @(Thread: 'GLThread 8919')
04-18 23:45:04.824: W/InputDispatcher(136): channel '418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-18 23:45:04.824: E/InputDispatcher(136): channel '418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-18 23:45:04.840: I/WindowManager(136): WIN DEATH: Window{418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity paused=false}
04-18 23:45:04.929: W/ActivityManager(136): Force removing ActivityRecord{418f6170 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/.SpeedyMindActivity}: app died, no saved state
04-18 23:45:04.972: W/InputDispatcher(136): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity (server)'
04-18 23:45:05.031: W/WindowManager(136): Force-removing child win Window{41951328 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity paused=false}
04-18 23:45:05.203: I/WindowManager(136): WINDOW DIED Window{418640c8 com.aqif.speedyMind.activity/com.aqif.speedyMind.activity.SpeedyMindActivity paused=false}
```

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: I am afraid I can't help, however I am facing the same error message - in a different context though... In regard to my issue, I suspect that it is related to Views and maybe how/when/if they get cleaned up. A possible scenario would be: The system tries to route an Input Event to a widget (or an Activity?) that no longer exists/is null... However I have no idea how to track this down/fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't came up with a solution for this problem. But better approach is to cache your Scenes and replace your Scenes from your engine.